# libtorrent + boost: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6random13random_deviceD1Ev

Tags: python, ubuntu, boost, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

I try to install [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/) and Python bindings in a py3.4 virtualenv:

```
./configure --enable-python-binding \  
--with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \  
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu/" \ 
--with-boost-python=boost_python-py34 \  
--prefix=/pyenvs/p3 \  
--with-boost-random=libboost_random
```

But have this error

```
In [1]: import libtorrent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ce6253f809d8> in <module>()
----> 1 import libtorrent

ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtorrent-rasterbar.so.9: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6random13random_deviceD1Ev
```

I have `libboost1.55-all-dev` installed on Ubuntu 14.04.
What (exactly) can cause this error?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution in the end?

Comment: Nope, I didn't find it

Comment: are you sure that boost lib you passed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` contains all the libboost* libraries? more specifically is `libboost_random.so` in there?